# Getting data to show in ListView DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, datatemplate

This is probably something simple I'm missing, but I have a ListView with an ItemTemplate and DataTemplate:

```
                         <ListView Name="IngredientsListBox">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IngredientName}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

and data passed to it in the code behind:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        var selectedRecipe = e.Parameter as Recipe;
        if (selectedRecipe != null)
        {

            _ingredientViewModel = new IngredientViewModel(selectedRecipe);
            IngredientsListBox.DataContext = _ingredientViewModel.Ingredients;
        }
    }
```

When I run the code, _ingredientViewModel.Ingredients shows the three ingredients passed to it from the data source, but they're not displaying on the XAML page. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there any databind method on ListView...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore my original answer if you read it. The ItemsSource isn't being set anywhere. Instead of setting IngredientsListBox.DataContext, set IngredientsListBox.ItemsSource

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I was being dumb. I appreciate it!